# How do I define a slice of slices containing an int and a slice of strings in Go?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, go, slice

It would look something like this:

`[[1,["a", "b", "c"]], [2,["z", "x", "y"]]]`

Intuitively I would do something like [][]int[]string, but that's not valid: `syntax error: unexpected [, expecting semicolon or newline or }`, so how would I do it?

Comment: [RTFM](https://golang.org/ref/spec) on [Slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) and [Struct](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) and types as well as the [Arrays, slices (and strings)](https://blog.golang.org/slices) blog entry.

Comment: Don't let the down votes get you down. Good luck on learning Go. I am learning it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slice of T: `var x []T`

Slice of slice of T: `var x [][]T`

Slice of T1 and T2: You need to put T1 and T2 into a struct.

So for: slice of (slices containing { int and a slice of strings } ).
It would usually be something like:

```
type foo struct {
    i int
    s []string
}
var x [][]foo
```

But your example looks more like just a `[]foo`:

```
bar := []foo{
    {1, []string{"a", "b", "c"}},
    {2, []string{"z", "x", "y"}},
}
fmt.Println("bar:", bar)
// bar: [{1 [a b c]} {2 [z x y]}]
```

[<kbd>Run on Playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/ebg91kzWPR) (also includes more examples)

Comment: Note, you can do things like `var x [][]struct{x, y int}` but usually it's simpler to just define a struct type as shown.